# Error getting ManyToMany field from an object

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

How to execute some functionality, after creating an object in the admin area? I'm trying to use post_save signal and trying to get all objects from my field, which has type ManyToMany, I also use sorting package (sortedm2m). When I save the object I try to output this field, but when I create I get an empty queryset, and when I edit I get the old queryset, without the current changes.

```
class Servers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="name")
    content = SortedManyToManyField(Content)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Servers)
def create_server(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.content.all())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)

Otherwise you can not be able to catch manytomany fields in signal.

Comment: Hi. Thank you!
And how can I trace the ForeignKey? Like I still have tabularinline. I'm using post_save now and I get "Servers has no likes."

Comment: I need more details for your question. Please provide models as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856302/error-when-getting-the-value-of-a-field-with-type-onetoonefield