# Error when getting the value of a field with type OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I encountered a problem that I can't get the value of a field with type OneToOneField. I am linking 2 models using Tabularinline. And I want to get the value from the linked model when I create the object. I am trying to use signals, namely post_save. When I save I get this error: "Servers has no info". How can I get info object when creating Servers object or after creating it?

```
class Servers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ServerInfo(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField()
    server = models.OneToOneField(Servers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="info")


@receiver(post_save, sender = Servers)
def create_server2(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    print(instance.info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
instance.info.all()
```